# Wrong format of the returned object when calculating values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem with the calculation of burned calories.

```
@calories_burned.each do |calories|
  json.child! do
    json.calories_burned calories.calories_burned(@calories_burned)
    json.week_number calories.week_number
  end
end
```

The number of calories burned, I figured method `calories_burned`
In the method is passed an object with fields `exercises_count` and `week_nubmer`.
Calories are computed as: exercises_count * 3.
The problem is, when I return the value received, came back the entire array.

```
def calories_burned(grouped_by_weeks)
  grouped_by_weeks.map { |x| x.exercises_count * 3 }
end
```

Example of what happens:

```
[{"calories_burned":[3,4],"week_number":17},{"calories_burned":[3,4],"week_number":22}]
```

Example of how it should be.

```
[{"calories_burned":3,"week_number":17},{"calories_burned":4,"week_number":22}]
```

Comment: This `grouped_by_weeks.map { |x| x.exercises_count * 3 }` will return an array - it's how you get [3,4].  What is the logic for wanting just `3` there?  Ie what, in english, should the `calories_burned` method do?  Is it meant to be the sum of the numbers in the array?  Also, how do you get the integer 4 as a result of multiplying something by the integer 3?  That seems impossible from a mathematical point of view.  Are these just random numbers rather than the actual result of calling the method?

Comment: @MaxWilliams `3` - this number for example. I should not return an array. 
As in the example which I have attached.

Comment: But just saying "it should return 3" doesn't really explain what you want it to do.  You pass an array in, you map it to another array, but you just want a single number.  Should the single number be one of the elements of the input array?  One of the numbers in the result of `map`?  Something else?  With questions like this you should explain what you are trying to achieve, in english, rather than in code or by saying "it should return 3".  Then people can tell you how to fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the array `@calories_burned` to the method `calories.calories_burned()`, which then goes over the whole array, returning the computation you specify.

To achieve what you intended, I think you meant to pass only the *current* object, which is strange in itself, since it is `calories` itself, so the minimal effort fix would be:

```
@calories_burned.each do |calories|
  json.child! do
    json.calories_burned calories.calories_burned
    json.week_number calories.week_number
  end
end

class Calories
  def calories_burned
    exercises_count * 3
  end
end
```

Though I would think hard about changing the naming of your objects, `@calories_burned`, `calories`, `calories.calories_burned` - these names are very confusing and do not convey the meaning of the object they represent. Maybe better names would be `@exercise_reports`, `exercise_report` and `exercise_report.calories_burned`?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I renamed the object as you suggested.